# JQuery Ajax call adding adding callback method within returned JSON string

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I using Jquery to make Ajax calls like this:

```
$.ajax({
           type:  "GET",
           url: webMethod,
           data: parameters,
           dataType: "jsonp",
           success: function(msg) {
              XXXX(msg.d);
           },
           error: function(e) {
         MessageBox("error","An error occured while fetching data.Please try again:<br>"+ e.statusText);
           }
       });
```

Once the call is made, I get a SyntaxError: Parse error message:

Checking the returned Jsonp string using a validator, if find something very wierd. The callback is found Both at beginning of string and within the string  i.e something like

```
jQuery171011899920250289142_1333375884404({"d":{"__type":"WebServices.XXXXXXXX","Status":2,.....jQuery171011899920250289142_1333375884404("Description":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",......
```

Notice that the illegal callback method string found within the string is similar to the one outside the json string.
I am using jquery 1.7. the behaviour is the same in 1.4
What is causing the callback method string to be embedded within the JSON string??

Answer (score 0):

The contents of the JSONP return value are coming from your server.  I'd suggest you look at the full URL being sent to the server and make sure the URL parameters are as you expect.  Then, look at whether the server is doing what it's supposed to.  The first `jQuery171011899920250289142_1333375884404()` that wraps your returned JSON is expected for a JSONP response.  The other one inside the JSONP response must be getting put there by your server so that's the place to look.

Comment: As you said, this has something to do with the server side. Indeed,the data returned if fetched from a DB. It working well for data from my developement server but failing in the production data. So, a more specific question is...WHAT in the data could be triggering the callback string to suddenly appear within the data??

Comment: @jordankoskei - you will have to show/tell us more.  What is the full URL including all query parameters being sent to the server?  What is the documentation for what the server is supposed to be sent and supposed to return?  We don't know anything about your server API or what you're sending it so it's hard for us to offer anything specific.  It is sometimes helpful to see the network trace of exactly what is going both ways over the network.